# error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut

Tags: java, spring-aop

All the classes in project are in com.aspect package.

The main Aspect :

```
@Aspect
public class MainAspect {

    @Pointcut("within(com.aspect..*)")
    public void standaloneLayer(){}

}
```

Another aspect for joinpoints having account object as argument:

```
 @Aspect
    public class AccountAspect {

        @After("com.aspect.MainAspect.standaloneLayer() && args(account)")
        public void pointCutForAccount(JoinPoint joinPoint, Account account){

        }
    }
```

Service layer class:

```
@Service
public class Customer {
    public void setAccountBalance(Account account) {}
}
```

While running application I am getting below exception:

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 formal unbound in pointcut
  at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:317)
```

Comment: Fixed it by change value attribute to pointcut attribute in @AfterThrowing annotation

Answer (score 4):

In my case the reason was that I imported the wrong class. Make sure that the class you import is `org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint` and not any thing else.

Answer (score 3):

Crosscheck your code once more whether you have imported  org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint instead of org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint
Note for AspectJ AOP you need to import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;





@Aspect
public class LoggingAspect {
@Before("allCircleMethods()")
    public void LogginAdvice(JoinPoint joinpoint)
    {
    System.out.println("advice is run");
    System.out.println(joinpoint.toString());
    }


@Before("args(String)")
public void StringArguementMethods()
{
    System.out.println("A method that takes String arguement has been called");
}


@Pointcut("execution(* get*())")
public void allgetters()
{}

@Pointcut("within(as.model.Circle)")
public void allCircleMethods()
{}

}
```

when i imported import org.aopalliance.intercept.Joinpoint; i got 0 ubound in poincut error , so i changed the import to org.aspect.lang.JoinPoint and my program ran successfully

Comment: I made the same mistake and this can be attributed to the Intellisense suggestions from IDE. One may not pay close notice to these two classes from different packages and capitalization difference in the names. I spent 2 hours before I saw this and thank you.